# What is the difference between these three methods?

Tags: java

```
String[] things = {"hello", "plastic", "eggs"};
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

//Add datas to my list type1
for (int i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
    list1.add(things[i]);
}
//Add my data to my list type2
for (String s : things) {
    list1.add(s);
}
//Add my data to my list type3
list1.addAll(Arrays.asList(things));
```

Comment: Difference in what respect?  Functionally speaking, the all achieve the same thing.

Comment: Really? 3 upvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
    list1.add(things[i]);
}
```

This is a `for loop` which executes as long as the condition `(i < things.length)` holds true.

```
//Add my data to my list type2
for (String s : things) {
    list1.add(s);
}
```

This is a `for-each` loop. It is different from `for loop` in a way that you don't need to specify the condition until which you want to execute the loop. It executes once for each item in the `things` array.

```
//Add my data to my list type3
list1.addAll(Arrays.asList(things));
```

In this method, `Arrays` class is used. `asList` method of `Arrays` class returns a list backed by a specified array, in your case, that array is `things`. Each item in list returned by `asList` method then gets added to `list1` using `addAll` method.

Basically, **they all do the same thing**, i.e. add all the items of `things` array in `list1` arraylist.

Comment: (2) creates an Iterator object. (3) creates an array wrapper object and the underlying array is cloned by `addAll` before adding, so it's comparably inefficient. (1) seems most efficient but I assume modern compiler will be able to convert (2) into (1) under the hood. Then again in (3) the array list capacity will only be increased once, because target size is known immediately. TL;DR: Efficiency depends on size of the added array.

Answer (score 1):

They all do the same thing but vary in complexity

1. First one is most native and uses index
2. Second one uses string iterator in foreach loop style
3. Third one uses eachmethod styled addition

Point to note is that advanced method like 3rd one may not be supported in lower versions of java like android_sdk<20